# Xamarin.Forms Plugin.Geofence giving System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: exception, xamarin.forms, geofencing

I am using [Plugin.Geofence](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Geofence) i Implemented its interface,Installed its dependencies i.e. `.NETStandard 2.0` and `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location`.

I am getting this exceptions `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` when i run `StartMonitoring` method.

I am calling this method in the `App()` Constructor.

```
    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

        CrossGeofence.Current.StartMonitoring(new GeofenceCircularRegion("MyRegion", 31.475085, 74.305833, 200)
        {

            //To get notified if user stays in region for at least 5 minutes
            NotifyOnStay = true,
            StayedInThresholdDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
        });
    }
```

Tried everything but couldn't resolve this

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution to this, ensure that before calling "CrossGeofence.Current" that the correct permissions have been requested and granted. If not, you'll see this error.